# Why is it possible to mix in classes in a type field?

Tags: class, scala

Why can I say that a type field has the type of a class with another class mixed into it (when only traits can be mixed in a class) ?

Example:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B extends A
defined class B
```

Mixing in `B` to `A` is not allowed:

```
scala> new A with B
<console>:10: error: class B needs to be a trait to be mixed in
             new A with B
                        ^
```

But this is possible:

```
scala> class E {type T = A with B}
defined class E

scala> new E
res1: E = E@1f2bc83
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between the mixin instantiation and the compound type definition.
First of all the type `A with B` exists and is exactly the type `B`, alas it is perfectly legal in scala to write

```
val x: A with B = new B
```

as is

```
val y: Any with AnyRef with A with B = new B
```

as it describes exactly the same type.
You are just introducing restrictions in the type of the value you can assign to a variable of that type.
These restrictions of course always hold in that case.

Furthermore you have to keep in mind that Scala does not necessarily need a type to be inhabited - i.e. the bottom type `Nothing` may not be instantiated at all.
But as `Nothing` is a subtype of every type that can be expressed in Scala it is even valid to write an expression like

```
def foo: AnyRef with AnyVal = sys.error("IMPOSSIBRU!")
```

`Nothing` is a subtype of `AnyRef with AnyVal` by definition thus that declaration typechecks.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [compound type](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/110) and has nothing to do with traits. It allows you to express that a type is a subtype of several other types.

For more information where they can occur see the [Scala tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) in section "type handling".

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: why is this possible?

Comment: @RobinGreen: Why should it not be possible? `new A with B` means *mixin* `B` to `A`, `type T = A with B` means `T` is of type `A` *and* `B`.

Comment: @Antoras -- the question is valid. Since you cannot _instantiate_ a mix two classes, what is a useful situation where you can have compound type of two classes? While the whole system is still sound, one could argue that when in `A with B` those two types are known to the compiler to refer to classes, it could emit a warning at least.

Comment: @Sciss: Ok, I hadn't thought at that. I agree, if both are classes the compiler should throw an error.

Comment: @Sciss: If I understood you right, you mean, since it is impossible to have an object having two class types which are not in a subtype relationship, it makes no sense to allow a compound type of `A with B` and therefore an warning/error should be thrown by the compiler ?

Comment: Well, yes, I would think so. On the other hand it is harmless, you cannot do anything wrong in the end... But I don't know if there is a corner case where such as statement might be useful.